# WPF ContextMenu Disable Item Icon

Tags: wpf

In the context menu item, there is a divider with the left side allocated to the icon. How can I remove that part so that only text appears in the item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747082.aspx) you find an example on how changing the control template of a MenuItem.
With this, you can style your menu-items as you desire.

Comment: I was hoping there'd be something like IconEnabled = "false" :(

Comment: It's never that simple in WPF.